# parameter storage for time-based simulations

Tags: configuration, architecture, point-in-time

we have a production application that depends on some business parameters such as thresholds, tax-rates, VAT etc. these parameters are subject to changes from time to time.

Therefore - we don't want to hard-code them but rather have them configured at some kind of parameter-storage change system so that they can be changed on-the-fly without involving development and code-deployemnts.

also, this application constantly runs regression tests against old payments on which we assert the results matches. ideally we would like to store these parameters' values with their time-point so that when the application fetches these parameters for an old payment it picks the parameter that was valid **at the time of the original calculation**

is there any know parameter-as-a-service that supports that? (I noticed that while aws's parameter-store [supports versioning](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/amazon-ec2-systems-manager-parameter-store-adds-support-for-parameter-versions/), for example, supports time-points, it is  and far from being elegant and requires cumbersome adaptations)

thanks in advance

Comment: I do not know if there is a service to work like a `parameter-as-a-service` but I have worked in a project with similar scenario. We create a structure on our system to persist the parameter history and cache it in a redis. When the application need the parameter, given a `key`, it reads the cache and look for a date. In my case when there is no date to search, it take the last valid defined parameter for a given `key`. I know it does not help anyway...